# Is it possible to retrieve Location wise data of product in mysql?

Tags: mysql, join, select, group-by, count

| id | product | location | year | month | order_share |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | DAP | Portland | 2022 | Jan | 12.55 |
| 2 | DAP | Portland | 2022 | Feb | 22 |
| 3 | DAP | Portland | 2022 | Mar | 15 |
| 4 | DAP | Portland | 2022 | Apr | 522 |
| 5 | DAP | Portland | 2022 | May | 55 |
| ---------------------------------------------------- |  |  |  |  |  |

Comment: I want following o/p

Comment: Please show your query and expected result